# iOS returns a UTC time of the 24th hour every once in a while

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Every once in a  while, I've noticed some dates on multiple users' devices return an hour 24 when asking for the UTC time from my date formatter. When I try and turn this into a date, it returns nil. I believe the hours are from 0-23, not up to 24.

Here is my date formatter code and how I am using it...

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    get {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        return formatter
    }
}
func toUTCAsString(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = dateFormatter
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

dateFormatter.toUTCAsString(Date())
```

Any ideas as to why ever so often this method will return a 24 for the hour? Here is an example of what it returns `2017-05-23T24:01:54.482+0000`

Comment: make sure you set the `formatter.locale` to `"en_US_POSIX"`

Comment: how does this make a difference if my `timeZone` is already set to UTC? I believe I am confused as to what setting the locale will do to the time. @LeoDabus

Comment: Locale and TimeZone are totally different things. If you don't set the locale your formatter  will be affected by the users locale device region format settings. Try it and let me know if it fixed your issue.